# Using Countifs to count only unique values based on a defferent data range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, distinct, countif

I trying to create dynamic report out of a work sheet I have and I am kind of stuck not able to get unique values.

In A1:A15000k I have Ticket/Task#, the ticket can be worked on more than once, i am trying to apply another criteria to my formula to only allow unique Ticket numbers to be counted.

here is the formula i am using now:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT($C$3 & "!$G$1:$G$14989"),INDIRECT(D3),INDIRECT($C$3 & "!$S$1:$S$14989"),$B$3, INDIRECT($C$3 & "!$H$1:$H$14989"), E$10, INDIRECT($C$3 & "!$U$1:$U$14989"), ">="& $C$7, INDIRECT($C$3 & "!$U$1:$U$14989"), "<="& $D$7))
```

Non dynamic version of it

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($G$1:$G$14989,Names, $H$1:$H$14989, "Priority", $N$1:$N$14989, ">=3/15/2016", $N$1:$N$14989, "<=3/16/2017"))
```

where Names represent a set of users....

[image]

Comment: If you would show some test data and expected output it would help us in understanding your problem better.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have add a sample of the data, the expected result for the formula should be 29

Thanks in advanced for your taking the time to help...

Answer (score 0):

I gut this finally working but with a helper column... just added a new column to my original sheet that is checking duplicates n the column i don't want to count when its duplicated

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$6:$C6,C6)>1,"DUPLICATE",1)
```

After that all i needed to do a dd the new column to my countifs formula...